# deploy java ee application to another port than 8080

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-deployment-project

Just wonder if i can deploy my java ee application in any application server for eg: glassfish, and user are able to access without typing the port number, for eg:**http://abc.com**
(my current application url will be **http://abc.com:8080**)

as from my knowledge, i might need another web server like for eg:Apache to redirect request to application server using mod_proxy module in order for me to achieve that, right?

kindly advise...

Answer (score 1):

Setting up Apache to proxy requests from port 80 to your app/web server running on port 8080 is *one* way to eliminate the need for port numbers in your URLs. But it's certainly not the only way. You should be able to configure any J2EE application server or web server to run on port 80 instead of 8080 (a common default in J2EE app/web servers). The details of the configuration editing are app/web server specific. You may need root privileges on your system to bind to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it to bind to port 80 instead of 8080, which is usually well documented how to since this is a common operation.

Note:  Under Unix systems you need to be root to bind to port 80 - here an Apache frontend might be useful.